# Do Akka Streams leverage Akka Actors?

Tags: scala, akka, actor, akka-stream

I started learning [Akka Streams](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-M2/scala/stream-index.html), which is a framework for processing data with back-pressure functionality. The library is part of [Akka](http://akka.io) that describes itself as:

> Akka is a toolkit and runtime for building highly concurrent,
>   distributed, and resilient message-driven applications on the JVM.

These capabilities comes from the nature of Akka actors. However, from my perspective, stream processing and actors are irrelevant concept to each other.

Question:
Do Akka Streams take advantage of these features of Akka actors? If yes, would you explain how actors help streams?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Akka Streams is a higher level abstraction than actors. It's an implementation of Reactive Streams which builds **on top** of the actor model. It takes advantage of all the actor features because it uses actors.

You can even go back to using actors directly in any part of the stream. Look at  ActorPublisher and ActorSubscriber.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't notice Akka Stream is built on top of actors. Let me explore the two classes. Will select an answer in few days.

Comment: Akka stream *flow* defines immutable blueprint, and the process called *materializations* (with parameters) run them as the "highly concurrent, distributed, and resilient message-driven" flow on top of Akka actors.

Answer (score 5):

A good starting point is the [akka stream quickstart](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/scala/stream-quickstart.html#Transforming_and_consuming_simple_streams).

**Yes**, an `Actor` is used to "materialize" each {`Source`, `Flow`, `Sink`} of a `Stream`.  This means that when you create a Stream nothing actually happens until the stream is materialized, typically via the `.run()` method call.

As an example, here is a Stream being defined:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Source, Flow, Sink}

val stream = Source.single[String]("test")
                   .via(Flow[String].filter(_.size > 0))
                   .to(Sink.foreach{println})
```

Even though the stream is now a `val` no computation has actually happened.  The Stream is just a recipe for computation.  To actually kick-off the work the Stream needs to be materialized.  Here is an example that does not use implicits to clearly show how materialization occurs:

```
val actorSystem = ActorSystem()
val materializer = ActorMaterializer()(actorSystem)

stream.run()(materializer)  //work begins
```

Now 3 Actors (at least) have been created: 1 for the `Source.single`, 1 for the `Flow.filter`, and 1 for the `Sink.foreach`.  Note: you can use the same `materializer` to initiate other streams

```
val doesNothingStream = Source.empty[String]
                              .to(Sink.ignore)
                              .run()(materializer)
```